# Why is el needed as view parameter

Tags: backbone.js

Since you can specify a view's el as one of it's properties why does it still need to be passed as a parameter to work?

Eg.

```
var DetailsView = Backbone.View.extend({    
   el: $(".details")
});
```

As parameter:

```
var DetailsView = new DetailsView({ el: $(".details") });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't need to be specified. If you already at that point have an element that matches the selector, this should work:

```
$('body').append($("<div class='details'></div>"));

var DetailsView = Backbone.View.extend({    
   el: $(".details")
});

console.log(new DetailsView().el.className); // details
```

I suspect that your element is not in DOM when you define the view.

How `Backbone.View` works is that it checks whether you specified `el` as an attribute and if not, it checks if `el` was specified in the prototype, and if not, it uses the `tagName`, `className` and `attributes` properties on the prototype to create a new element for the view.

Comment: Using a selector string (`el: '.details'`) would also work as long as `.details` was around when you said `new DetailsView` (http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/FG4vq/).